how to make table fit page
my table goes way off my page. how can i make them all appear on single page.

pls see latex code
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| c|}
\hline
Measure & {NormCnts} & {LFC}  & Up/down Expressed & CPM & TPM & RPKM  & rlog & VST\\ \hline
Scale & [0-$\infty$] & [0-$\infty$]  & [0 or 1] & [0-$\infty$] & [0- $\infty$]  & & [0- $\infty$] & [0- $\infty$] \\ \hline
Type & Discrete & Discrete & Binary  & Continuous  & Continuous & & rlog & VST\\ \hline
Mean & Bimodal (highest peak) & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue&insertValue & rlog & VST\\ \hline
Var & Heavy tailed (centered on 2500)  & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue& insertValue& rlog & VST\\ \hline
Special & insertValue  & insertValue & insertValue &  insertValue& insertValue& corrected for gene length & Var Stabilizing & Var Stabilizing\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Comparison of various transformation techniques of gene expression.}
\label{table:Y_compare}
\end{table}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Does maybe something in this Q&A help you?

Please tell us (a) which document class you employ and (b) how wide the textblock is or, alternatively, how wide the margins are.

i used this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]

Note that you can always edit you question and add important information, which might be better than just a comment

Off-topic: You should not use \begin{center}…\end{center} inside the table environment. → Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?

Given that the table has 9 columns and that automatic line breaking is possible in only 5 of these columns, my main suggestions are to (a) render the table in landscape mode and (b) employ a tabularx envionment instead of a tabular environment, with line breaking employed in 5 of the 9 columns. (In the code shown below, observe that the sum of the relative column widths, 5, of these columns equals their number, 5. Note also that the usable width of column 2 is twice that of columns 8 and 9.)

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[letterpaper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % center cell contents vertically

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{|l|C{1.6}|c|C{0.9}|c|c|C{0.9}|C{0.8}|C{0.8}|}
\hline
Measure & {NormCnts} & {LFC} & Up/down Expressed & CPM & TPM & RPKM & rlog & VST \\ 
\hline
Scale & 0--$\infty$ & 0--$\infty$ & 0 or 1 & 0--$\infty$ & 0--$\infty$ & & 0--$\infty$ & 0--$\infty$ \\ 
\hline
Type & Discrete & Discrete & Binary & Continuous & Continuous & & rlog & VST \\ 
\hline
Mean & Bimodal (highest peak) & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & rlog & VST \\ 
\hline
Var & Heavy tailed (centered on 2500) & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & rlog & VST \\ 
\hline
Special & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & insertValue & corrected for gene length & Var Stabilizing & Var Stabilizing \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Comparison of various transformation techniques of gene expression.}
\label{table:Y_compare}

\end{table}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}

